# Estimate size of zip files

Tags: powershell, zip

Taking a shot here. Are there any tools (including PowerShell) to estimate the size of a folder that will be zipped? For example, I have about 500 folders in a directory and need to zip each one individually so the main directory will show 500 zip files. Before I go through all the trouble of zipping these folders, I would like to know how much space I would actually be saving. This is in Win 2012r2 in a standard directory.

Comment: There is no way of knowing unless you actually compress the data. Without doing that, you could only make some very rough estimates, e. g. by looking at the file types. If there are mostly files that are already compressed in some way (e. g. PNG or JPEG files), then you won't save much space by zipping them.

Answer (score 0):

The ratio of compression depend (as already mentioned in comment) very much from the data. Here is one example with 1MB files one with zero, second with random data (it is in Linux, but you will get the point):

```
# ls -l
-rw-r--r--    1 name    UsersGrp   1048576 Sep 19 19:11 rand_file
-rw-r--r--    1 name    UsersGrp   1048576 Sep 19 19:11 zero_file
# zip random rand_file
  adding: rand_file (deflated 0%)
# zip zero zero_file
  adding: zero_file (deflated 100%)
                                                                                                                               # ls -l
total 1539
-rw-r--r--    1 name    UsersGrp   1048576 Sep 19 19:11 rand_file
-rw-r--r--    1 name    UsersGrp   1048904 Sep 19 19:14 random.zip
-rw-r--r--    1 name    UsersGrp      1201 Sep 19 19:14 zero.zip
-rw-r--r--    1 name    UsersGrp   1048576 Sep 19 19:11 zero_file
```